# Structure From Motion From Multiple Views w/ MATLAB

Tags: matlab, projection, point-clouds, structure-from-motion

I am a novice when it comes to the topic of Structure From Motion. I have been trying to follow the tutorial here in the MathWorks webpage for SFM: [LINK](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/structure-from-motion-from-multiple-views.html).

However, after running the code, I get this error message:

```
Warning: Maximum number of trials reached. Consider increasing the maximum
distance or decreasing the desired confidence. 
> In vision.internal.ransac.msac (line 136)
  In estimateEssentialMatrix (line 161)
  In helperEstimateRelativePose (line 43)
  In PERFORM_SFM (line 70) 
Error using helperEstimateRelativePose (line 70)
Unable to compute the Essential matrix

Error in PERFORM_SFM (line 70)
    [relativeOrient, relativeLoc, inlierIdx] = helperEstimateRelativePose(...
```

Could someone help me understand why this is happening? Could someone provide me an different approach?

Comment: Have you considered increasing the maximum distance or decreasing the desired confidence

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, and hence the question... :)

Comment: @troymyname00 same tutorial and error :-) did u figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Nope...I did not. I switched to Python, and found an open-source tool that performs SFM easily.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to solve this same error. In my case, it seems I was using too many images, so the resulting equation system was overdetermined and, therefore, the matrix could not be computed. I just tested with a number of images similar to the example (6, in my case) and enough camera movement from frame to frame, and it works like it should.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ander Biguri said, consider increasing the maximum distance or decreasing the desired confidence. You can do this by modifying the Matlab built-in function *helperEstimateRelativePose.m*: *line 43*. Then you can add as many images as you want. After modification, it should look like this:

```
 [E, inlierIdx] = estimateEssentialMatrix(matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2,...
    cameraParams, 'Confidence', 50, 'MaxDistance', 5);
```

But be careful editing the built-in functions. In my case, I modified the function and saved into another folder by another name and add that folder into path.
I hope this will help someone.